# regex wont work - bat pattern still right

Tags: javascript, regex

my regex are not working. I cant understand Why.

```
let text = '0x00d38f0ff55cf1b18841a7e7993eb5b1df791f7be40a828b94e6df90dafd9d722021-11-28 23:08:3918 hrs 5 mins ago0xba4090fb813a5da6c24d53149d98d8539e2469caOUT PancakeSwap V2: HTD-BUSD 1445.871849548172161305 HeroesTD (HTD)';

let regex = new RegExp("(.*?)2021(.*?)ago(.*?)(IN|OUT)(.*?)\\s(.*?)\\s\^", "gm");
    
let result;
result = regex.exec(text);
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: There seems to be no match for `\^`

Comment: Why do you think the pattern is right?

Comment: Doesn't match the `\\s` and the `\^` token

Comment: What are you trying to match in that string?

Comment: Also, `\^` in a string is the same thing as `^`. If you're wanting to escape the `^` so that `new RegExp` treats it like a literal `^`, you'll need to do `\\^` inside the string so that the end result inside of the RegExp is `\^`. Otherwise the backslash is just an escape character for the string.

Comment: `\^` is a typo, without it, there is a match, and probably, it is as expected - see https://regex101.com/r/OmHHgK/1.

Answer (score -1):

The `\^` ends up matching the *beginning* of a line (since you're using the m modifier). Your string is has no newline characters in it, so its not possible to match that string with what you have right now.

The possible solutions I can think of are:

- Add a newline to the end of your string -- not the best option, unless you know your data will end up being formatted that way, which it might given that you're using the g and m modifiers.
- Replace the `\\s\^` with a `$`, since that matches the end of a line regardless of whether or not another line comes after it -- probably the better, cleaner option.

**Edit:**

For clarification, since you explicitly asked *why* it doesn't seem to be matching like you want. Your regex *does* match all the way up to the last `\s` you have, but fails at the `^`. There seems to be a lot of assumptions about what you want to match, and so the solution will vary accordingly. Yes, you could just remove the `\^` like others have suggested, but that would no longer match the whole line, stopping just at "PancakeSwap" which I can only assume is not what you want? Another way to "fix" this would be to remove the `\s\^` from the end of that string, and take that final `(.*?)` and make it greedy: `(.*)`. This "greediness" just means it will try to match as much as it can (for the most part), so removing the `\s^` will allow it to match all the way to the end of the line -- although this could backfire if there ends up being more lines after this. Again, I can only assume that you intend to match all the way to the end of the line, since that's what `\s^` is doing -- although its only doing that in the presence of another line proceeding it.